# Redux - Immutable Update Operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently writing a reducer for a simple add/delete/update app and I'm using React with Redux for it. There is a case where I want to update a `string` an `array` which looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  columns: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
  ...
}
```

This is my approach:

```
case ACTION:
  const columns = state.columns;
  return {
    ...state,
    columns: columns.map((column, index) => {
      if(index !== action.index) {
        return column;
      }
      return action.column;
    });
  }
```

The Problem is, when I change a specific element in the array in the view (e.g. on index 2 is now 'col3new'), I want the new columns array to look like this: 
`columns: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3new', 'col4']`.

But the returned array is this: `columns: ['col3new', 'col1', 'col2', 'col4']` and I don't know why.

I know it's not allowed to mutate the state. But I'm returning a new array.

Comment: Are you sure that the index in the action is correct?  Can you post the action creator?

Comment: @markerikson Yeah, I'm sure: `export function changeColumnLabel(column, index) {
 return {
  type: ACTION,
  column,
  index
 }
}`

Comment: You know what? This is really creepy. I have an other operation in an other container component where I mapStateToProps and need the longest string from the columns array. I do this: `export function selectLongestString(array) {
 const longest = copy && copy.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length )[0];
 return (longest && longest.length) || 0;
}`. I store the return value in a prop for my other container component. This has a really bad side effect. But why does that happen?

Comment: Be careful with `sort`, it mutates the array itself.